# How to create Single Custom Action Filter in asp.net core to validate GET & POST request parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, custom-action-filter

Want to create 'Custom Action Filter' in asp.net core, which basically performs some validation logic on the incoming GET & POST request related input parameters then throw validation exception if validation fails or allow the execution to proceed further on validation success.

Is it possible to create one single 'Custom Action Filter' to validate GET & POST request parameters with out using 'if else'(like sample mentioned below)? As you all know usually parameter comes as part of query string for GET request whereas parameter comes as part of request body for POST request

Considering SRP principle, I don't want to create input parameter validation code as part of controller/action logic code.

I can't use Model validation in my case.

```
public class MyModel 
{
  public string id{ get; set; }

  public string orderId{ get; set; }
}

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] MyModel model)
    {
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(string id, string orderId)
    {
    }

   public class Validate : ActionFilterAttribute
   {
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)

    { 
      if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method == "GET" )
        {
           //consider parameters from query string
           //parameter validation logic
        }

        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method == "POST" )
        {
           //consider parameters from body
           //parameter validation logic
        }           

     }
   }
```

Comment: ASP.NET already has support for DTO/model validation - why not use that instead?

Comment: "Considering SRP principle, I don't want to create input parameter validation code as part of controller/action logic code." - I'll say right away that you misunderstand the SRP: it's perfectly fine for validation to happen inside a controller's action method. Sometimes it's essential because the validation/verification logic depends on some state or value that only the controller's action can get (e.g. verifying unused e-mail addresses within a particular tenant partition).

Comment: @Dai, "Sometimes it's essential because the validation/verification logic depends on some state or value that only the controller's action can get" but still controller's action can call dedicated validator class method with the state or value that only the controller's action knows to keep SRTP intact, right?

Comment: Middleware will be easier to use. Just invoke the context and do your processing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @GHDevOps, adding middleware will be applied globally to all request/response which I dont want.

Comment: No, middleware can be applied selectively if you use `MapWhen`. Also, **middleware is cheap**: it's runtime cost is a single allocation and an extra indirect jump, which is utterly, utterly trivial.

Comment: @Dai, you are right middleware can be applied selectively if you use MapWhen. In my validator I need to access DB to complete the validation, accessing DB repos from middleware not possible in my app architecture. Prefer 'Action filter' as it is the right fit for my use case.

Comment: What you're describing is _verification_ (as it involves DB/IO), that's not the same thing as _validation_ (which is concerned with satisfying static invariant constraints).